# Are there any words in English pronounced with /e/ at the end?

Tags: pronunciation, phonotactics

In first-language English pronunciation (Australian, British, American, etc., not Indian, Malaysian, etc.) are there any words with the /e/ (or /ɛ/) sound in "bed" /bed/ at the end of a word? As a counter-example "me" is pronounced /miː/. I don't know of any words ending in "e" where it is pronounced /e/; it is usually either /iː/ or silent. If you do know of any words please specify if they're limited to a certain dialect, region or accent.

Comment: No, there cannot be.  Terminal /e/ can only occur as diphthong, as in *they*.  And unstressed /ɛ/ will soon enough go the way of all things, despite what *bokeh* enthusiasts would have you believe.

Comment: Great! Want to post that as an answer?

Comment: The only exception I can think of is unassimilated Yiddish _meh_ 'display of disinterest', which is /mɛ/ in English. But the point is that it's **not** assimilated.

Comment: Heh, can we claim loanwords? *keffiyeh*, *tabouleh*…

Comment: @JohnLawler I did think of "meh" but discounted it as not being a "real" word. I like your use of "unassimilated". It's a much better way of saying that!

Comment: @choster I pronounce "tabouleh" as /tæbuːliː/.

Comment: @JohnLawler Meh is ***Yiddish***?! I... you... you're blowing my mind!

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not sure what you mean by assimilation here. If you mean [phonological assimilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(linguistics)), then I don't see what you mean because *meh* is not an example of a word where assimilation would be likely to happen. If you mean that it hasn't been widely adopted in English usage, then I disagree with you.

Comment: @PeterOlson Your last sentence shows the disparity in ages between you and John.

Comment: I meant that its pronunciation hadn't assimilated to the English norm yet. That's what happens to borrowed words in any language. That's why the Japanese word for "baseball" has four syllables.

Comment: @John, the Japanese word for baseball has six syllables (since the Japanese notion of syllables is the mora): ベースボール _be-e-su-bo-o-ru_—or rather, three, if you take the _Japanese_ word for baseball, 野球 _ya-kyu-u_. I'm not sure if _meh_ is really likely to assimilate to any ‘English norm’, either; rather, the norm seems to be changing to allow final /ɛ/ in new words, at least monosyllables.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm not so sure that *meh* breaks the norm: the vowel is in an accented syllable, so it is unlikely to degrade into /ə/, and it seems to follow the pattern of similar monosyllabic utterances such as *heh*, *eh*, and *yeh*.

Comment: Possibly. _Eh_ is pronounced /e/ in my dialect, and _heh_ and _yeh_ don't occur; I've encountered them only in non-American writing and don't really know how they're sposta be pronounced.

Comment: heh = huh /hə/, eh /æɪ/, yeh = yeah /jeː/

Comment: Topically relevant: [xkcd: Intervocal fortition](http://www.xkcd.com/1697/) and ["English doesn't allow one-syllable words to end in a lax vowel, so writers on The Simpsons decided to mess with future linguists by introducing the word 'meh.'" (xkcd rollover text)](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=26341) See the LL links for how 'unnatural' rules come about.

Comment: @JohnLawler Don't you mean "sposteh be pronounced"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there cannot be.  **Phonemic** /e/ at the end of a word in English can only occur as a **phonetic** falling diphthong [ej], as in *say* or *they*. That’s why those have a ‹y› in our spelling today, and why *sleigh* has an ‹i› in it.

And unstressed /ɛ/ will soon enough go the way of all things, despite what *bokeh* enthusiasts would have you believe. (Same with the *meh*-sayers.) Because English [***phonotactics***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics) forbid an open /ɛ/ at the end of the word, those will therefore soon enough become either a phonemic schwa /ə/ — or else become a close vowel like /e/ or /i/ **phonemically** and so one with the characteristic falling **phonetic** diphthong [ej] or [ij] required by English phonotactics.

I therefore little doubt that the word currently spelled *bokeh* will end up /ˈbokə/ just like the *boca* heard in the city of Boca Raton, Florida, to rhyme with *mocha*.

The other two possibilities are for *bokeh* to wind up rhyming either with *hokey* or  else with *hockey*. This would be like how Spanish *chile* which ends with /e/ becomes in English *chili* which ends in /i/.

Only if the second syllable became stressed could *bokeh* become /boˈke/ or more likely /bəˈke/, which is the sort of thing you get when in English you pronounce the Spanish word *olé* under English phonotactic rules.

Whatever happens to words like *bokeh*  as they assimilate to English, they will need to be respelled to use a spelling similar to whatever words they end up rhyming with in order for them to be predictably pronounced by monoglot English readers.

Probably spelling what is now commonly rendered *bokeh* in English as *boka* would have been better from the get-go.

Comment: what is the IPA for bokeh, and what do you suggest it will be?

Comment: @marcellothearcane English phonotactics forbid an open /ɛ/ at the end of the word. It will therefore become either a schwa or else become a close vowel phonemically (and with a falling diphthong phonetically as again required by English phonotactics). I little doubt it will end up /ˈbokə/ just like the *boca* heard in the city of Boca Raton, Florida, to rhyme with *mocha*.  The other possibility is for it to end like Spanish *chile* /e/ > EN *chili* /i/ and so rhyme with *hokey* or *hockey*.  Only if the second syllable became stressed could it become /bəˈke/ as when in EN you say ES *olé*.

Comment: For the time being, though, /ˡbokɛ/ or /ˡboʊkɛ/ is fairly common, despite not being phonotactically valid. Either that will change as the word becomes more naturalised, or the phonotactics will change. The latter will probably require more than just the one word; perhaps the commonness of _meh_ is enough to help.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are.

But first of all, what dialect of English are you talking about? There are many different dialects of English, and answers to pronunciation questions will differ among them. Second, which sound are you actually talking about? There are more than one 'e' sounds you could be referring to, such as /eɪ/ (as in "rein"), /ɛ/ (as in "bed"), and /ə/ (examples differ greatly among dialects).

### Examples with /eɪ/

Dan already pointed out a number of examples. Here are some more:

- résumé
- purée
- toupée

I don't see why these should be disqualified just because they end with /eɪ/ rather than /e/, since a pure /e/ occurs very rarely, if at all, in most dialects of English. I also don't see why they should be disqualified because they are borrowed from French: almost 30% of words in English are from French.

If you consider the same sound but not spelled with the letter 'e', then there are many more examples, including

- clay
- say
- weigh

and so forth.

### Examples with /ɛ/

This does occur, although admittedly uncommonly, since English phonotactics tend to discourage final or unstressed /ɛ/. Such words tend to be monosyllabic interjections. Here are some examples:

- meh
- heh
- eh
- yeh

There are a number of borrowed words that may count, although some may pronounce them with /ə/ or /eɪ/.

- gefilte
- keffiyeh
- dahabieh
- bokeh

### Examples with /ə/

There are plenty of such examples, including

- the (unstressed)
- comma
- words ending in 'er' in some dialects: hotter, sharper, braver

Comment: I thought I was pretty specific. Australian, British, American, etc. dialects. I gave an exmaple of the sound. The /e/ sound, not /eɪ/ or /ə/. "bed" to me is /bed/, not /bæɪd/ (baid) or /bəd/ (~bud/~bd). Words like résumé should be disqualified because I was specifically disqualifying them. Maybe it would be clearer if I said that I pronounce "bed" as [bed] and not [bɛd]? The only example word you've given that works the way I pronounce it is gefilte, but only because I have a Jewish background. This word is also uncommon outside the Jewish community and unassimilated into regular English.

Comment: You pronounce 'bed' as /bed/ and not /bɛd/? I'm doubtful because I've never heard anybody prinounce it that way. [e] only occurs in rare situations in English and it is usually an allophone of /eɪ/.

Comment: I'm following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects which says that the sound /ɛ/ is realised as [e] in AuE and some NZE, RP, SAE & SSE. It seems to indicate that across all accents that [e] is at least as common as [ɛ], maybe more so. If you can explain the difference using only AuE then I might be convinced that the chart is wrong.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: Shouldn't *latke* be pronounced with the same vowel as *gefilte*? (Don't ask me ... I pronounce both of these with a schwa.)

Comment: @Peter Both https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/latke and https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/gefilte_fish give the final sound as /ə/, so it could actually be /e/. I don't know because I had to look up _latke_. Again, it hasn't assimilated into English; it still sounds like a Yiddish word.

Answer (score 6):

There are some unassimilated loanwords (mostly from French) that have a non-silent *e* at the end, which usually retain an acute accent to indicate the unusual-for-English pronunciation.  For example: *blasé, café, cliché, fiancé, flambé, frappé, macramé, olé, protégé, risqué, soufflé*, and *touché*.  However, there is a tendency to dipthongize the /e/ to /eɪ/, so this may not count.

Comment: I think that in French é is pronounced /e/ but, as you say, it becomes /eɪ/ in English. I was also hoping for less obviously foreign words.

Comment: Loanwords from Japanese get a similar distortion of the final vowel, as in _karaoke_, _anime_ and _sake_.

Comment: But those French words don't have the vowel of *bed* —  French words which end with the vowel of *bed* end with *-ait* or *-ais*, like *lait* or *frais*. Those have a different French vowel which doesn't exist in English, but which we replace with /eɪ/ in English.

Comment: @PeterShor but those French words do have the vowel /e/, which is the subject of the question. Dan: I think *olé* comes from Spanish.

Comment: @phoog: The OP says *the /e/ (or /ɛ/) sound in "bed" /bed/*.

Comment: @PeterShor so it is. I never noticed the puzzling rendition of *bed* as /bed/.

Comment: @phoog: Not that that makes any real difference to this answer – the only French word I can find that ends in /-ɛ/ and has been adapted into English is *palais*, and it's pronounced in English with the same ending /-eɪ/ as all the French words that originally ended in /-e/.

Comment: @PeterShor also true. English has a strong track record of losing distinctions between various French vowels when borrowing words (*lingerie* comes to mind).

Answer (score 3):

> In first-language English pronunciation . . . are there any words with
>   the /e/ (or /ɛ/) sound in "bed" /bed/ at the end of a word? [P]lease specify if they're limited to a certain dialect, region or
>   accent.

Yes, there's **kitteh**, which is common in *lolspeak*. You can hear it pronounced [here](http://forvo.com/word/kitteh/) (in both American and British English) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7EjHeASBKE) (I think maybe synthetically produced).

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kitteh):

> **Noun**
>
> **kitteh**
>
> (Internet, neologism) A cat, chiefly in a lolcat type picture.
>
> 2010, Martin Grondin, LOLcat Bible: In Teh Beginnin Ceiling Cat Maded
>   Teh Skiez An Da Urfs N Stuffs, ISBN 1569757348, page 96:
>   *You shud wership Ceiling Cat, teh God **Kitteh** ov Daniel.*

There are also a number of similar words, notably "itteh", "bitteh", and "committeh" as seen here:

[image: LOLCats picture of kittens in a box, captioned "itteh bitteh kitteh committeh: Think tank"]

---

OK, that sounds like a silly answer, but I actually think there's more to it than first appears. Lolspeak is an online variety of English ([digilect](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/292458634_The_effect_of_digilect_on_dialogue_letter)). Its exact nature is [still being debated](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-is-lolspeak-and-does-it-have-equivalents-in-languages-other-than-english), including [at ELL](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16154/is-lolspeak-bad-english-or-just-a-different-english), but linguists have begun studying it more systematically and it does seem to rise above the level of individual slang words or something like Pig Latin. See, for example, [Gawne & Vaughan, 2011](https://digitalcollections.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/9398/5/Gawne_ICanHaz2012.pdf) or [Fiorentini, 2014](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/linguistics/assets/documents/5.Fiorentini_NWPL.pdf).

More significantly for this question, some of these online conventions have crossed over into spoken English--my own kids use "OMG" (pronounced oh-em-gee) as an interjection much more frequently than "oh my gosh" or "oh my god" or similar. This phenomenon is also being studied, albeit primarily by younger scholars (many of the hits for ["spoken lolspeak" in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=spoken%20lolspeak&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C16) are for theses of various sorts, rather than published work).

In this context, the appearance of the apparently non-"English" pronunciation of kitteh, which is an English coinage, may suggest that a previously "impossible" word-ending sound has now become more natural for some significant portion of native English speakers as a result of an initially text-only trend.

I suspect that many of the folks who know the word "kitteh" would also know **meh**, **feh**, and **heh**--I have used all of these, which all rhyme. I take it from other answers here that meh and feh both come from Yiddish. Possibly "heh" in its internet sense does as well, or perhaps it is an English altering of "hah" modeled on those examples. Per [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heh) (sense 2, which includes an audio clip), it is an interjection indicating "Weak amusement, sometimes signaling boredom."

Given these one-syllable examples, it may be that the language (or at least some speakers thereof) is evolving to also allow multi-syllable words such as kitteh to retain their terminal /e/ or /ɛ/ sound.

---

TL;DR: Among some sub-sets of internet-generation native English speakers, several words ending in the vowel sound of "bed" are in current use, including **meh**, **heh** and the (lolspeak) English coinage **kitteh**.

Answer (score 2):

*Pace* Peter Olson, no one's mentioned the

### **Examples with /ɛ̃/**

This is the nasal version of ɛ that, like the click consonants in 'tsk, tsk, tsk,' makes vanishingly few appearances in English.

Here are two examples:

bleh/bleeah/bleah  - interjection of disgust/discomfort/indifference
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleh

"'weh weh weh' (or 'wah wah wah') cried the baby" - onomatopoeia, obviously

These are both native English as far as I can tell.

They both rhyme with 'Gauguin' (Eugène Henri Paul) (in my dialect anyway) -- the sound ɛ̃ is part of the regular vowel inventory in French. Educated English speakers seem to invoke it often enough to at least pronounce words like 'Gauguin' half-way correctly.

Comment: I take two issues with this one big one small. Big: 'bleah' does not have a nasal vowel for me (or for anyone I can imagine). Small: the spelling 'weh' doesn't correspond to anything in English for me (but yes, 'wah wah' is pronounced as a nasal when mimicking crying, but not for baby talk 'water')